# Building Grails test data for non GORM objects

Tags: testing, grails, mocking, grails-orm

We're building a Grails front-end to a REST based backend.  We have many value (DTOs) that we marshal to/from JSON.

I'm looking for a convenient way to build mocks of these DTOs for testing purposes. I like Grails' build-test-data and fixtures plugins, but I believe their intended purpose is for GORM objects.

Any recommendations for building test data for non-GORM objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [build-test-data](http://www.grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin leverages the grails constraints/validation (especially "nullable: false") and relational properties (belongsTo, hasMany, etc) to walk the dependency graph and build the smallest set of "required" objects and properties for the object you're trying to build.  That metadata is really what enables BTD to create a valid graph "automatically".

You're right that it doesn't work for regular DTOs because they don't conform to those conventions.

If your DTOs are simply POJOs/POGOs, you're probably best of with some sort of [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).  This [post by Nat Price](http://nat.truemesh.com/archives/000714.html) was the thing that inspired me to write build-test-data, and the pattern it outlines is still valid for objects that don't conform to conventions that GORM objects do.

Comment: Hi Ted,  thanks for link, looks good.  I found the following helpful as well: http://www.jworks.nl/2011/09/16/friday-repost-groovy-object-mother-pattern/  One of these days I'll get back to GUM and buy you a beer or two.

Comment: What about a POGO that implements `grails.validation.Validateable`?